# How to detect capabilities of remote Media buttons?

Tags: android, android-audiomanager, headset, android-mediasession

Apps like Google Play Music can detect what buttons the media controller has. For example, for wired headphones with a single button, pressing the button 2-3 times in succession will skip forward/back the track. If you use a bluetooth controller that has physical skip forward/back buttons, the play/pause button will not exhibit this behavior, rapidly clicking the play/pause button will rapidly play/pause the track.

How do these apps know the capabilities of the controller?

Answer (score 0):

There are three different keycodes which you can react to differently in your code

```
KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY
KEYCODE_MEDIA_PAUSE
KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE
```

You can measure the interval between keyevents and play/pause for single clicks and skip when a few close ones happen with the help of a handler.

Try checking which keycode you get from your different headsets, that might help solve the mystery